# Bezeichungen für "Füßefinger"

Tags: single-word-request

Wir haben einen Daumen, Zeige-, Mittel-, Ring- und kleinen Finger. Am Fuß haben wir den großen und den kleinen Zeh... Haben die anderen drei auch einen Namen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wikipedia ([https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zehe_(Fuß)#Begriffe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zehe_(Fu%C3%9F)#Begriffe)) sagt:

> Für die Digiti pedis II, III und IV existieren keine speziellen Bezeichnungen, weder in der Fach- noch in der Alltagssprache. Wörter für den zweiten und vierten Zeh zu finden war Teil des 3sat-Wettbewerbs „Uns fehlen die Worte“ im Jahr 2009. Anklang fand der naheliegende Vorschlag, sie analog zu den Fingern als Zeigezeh bzw. Ringzeh zu bezeichnen,[3] wobei zumindest der Zeigezeh bereits für 2003 belegt ist.[4] Diese Begriffe sind jedoch nicht in der Sprachgemeinschaft etabliert und deshalb auch in keinem Wörterbuch zu finden.

Comment: ... und auch nicht besonders sinnig, weill man mit dem einen nicht zeigt und am anderen gemeinhin keinen Ring trägt... ;)

Comment: @tofro: Naja, es wäre halt eine Analogie. Solche Wortbildung durch Analogien sind sehr häufig. Zum Beispiel _Windschatten_, welches dasjenige bezeichnet "was für den Wind das ist, was der Schatten für das Licht ist.", so wäre "Ringzeh" eben "der Zeh, der ein Ringfinger wäre, wenn er ein Finger wäre."

Comment: Möglicherweise haben Sprachen, die in Gegenden ansässig sind, wo man aufgrund des Klimas nicht so sehr auf Schuhe angewiesen ist wie im deutschen Sprachraum, es ein bißchen einfacher gehabt, dafür Bezeichnungen herauszuilden...

Comment: @tofro: Es gibt durchaus Ringe für Zehen und die werden, soweit ich weiß, tatsächlich vorzugsweise am vierten Zeh, also Ringzeh getragen. Eingerechnet den Mittelzeh, der auch ohne analogie zur Hand oder eine fragwürdige Funktionszuordnung funktioniert, wäre der zweite Zeh der einzige, für den ich keine andere Bezeichnung verwenden würde. Tolle Antwort.

Comment: Also ich habe durchaus (und bewusst humorvoll) den Begriff "Zeigezeh" schon sporadisch selber verwendet, das müsste ende der 90er gewesen sein. Ist einfach die naheliegende Analogie zu den Fingerbezeichnungen. Dass Menschen, die Zehenringe tragen, dies tendenziell auch am vierten tun, halte ich diesbezüglich für eher irrelevant.